# Center input in python cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, curses, python-curses

I'm working on a classic text-adventure port in python.

I'm wondering is it possible to center a users input?
I found out that using str.center() method, I can center the printed text, however, I can't center the python input() function. Using str.center() just gives me this:
[image: As you can see, the input starts in the middle but strafts rigth]

As you can see, the input starts in the middle but then just continues to the right

What I'd like to do is that whatever the user inputs, it goes in the middle like this:
[image: Mock]
(also if you're wondering, I didn't solve my own problem, this is just a mock using a print instead of an input)

**So I'm wondering how could I do that? Using the str.center() or Curses or something else altogether?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with curses. The `input()` and `str.center()` will not be that helpful since they do not know in advance how wide the screen is (and how to center the input string as you enter it).

With curses, you could use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.filter) function to set aside the current line of the screen (rather than erasing the whole screen...), create a window in that line using `newwin` and use [`mvwin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.mvwin) to adjust the window's position as entered (or alternatively just `move` within the original `stdscr`).  There are several ways to accomplish this with curses—but more complicated than `input()`.